# What is the best practice for implementing Google Analytics initTracker?

Tags: mobile, google-analytics, smartface.io

It seems `GlobalEventsOnStart`is a decent place to kick `Google.Analytics.initTracker` in smartface. What do you suggest?

Also where do I have to put `Google.Analytics.setSessionControl("end")`?

Answer (score 0):

es the best place to initTracker is GlobalEventsOnStart .

end for `setSessionControl("end");` can be useful on global on exit event.

```
function Global_Events_OnExit(e){
   setSessionControl("end"); 
}
```